# Как правильно связать BroadcastReceivers и Service?

Tags: java, android, broadcast-receiver, уведомления

В приложении я реализовал `push notification` с кнопками.

Вопрос вот в чем, мне нужно сделать загрузку файла в бекграунде, я делаю так, приходит `push notification` с двумя кнопками <kbd>Ок</kbd> и <kbd>Позже</kbd>, юзер нажимает <kbd>Ок</kbd> и отправляется интент на поиски `BroadcastReceivers`.

`BroadcastReceivers` получает интент и запускает `Service` и `Service` закачивает в бекграунде файл с сервера...

Мне нужно это все сделать так, чтоб приложение при этом не открывалось... Юзер прям в `push notification` нажал <kbd>Ок</kbd> и все загрузилось, правильно я выбрал схему?

Answer (score 1):

Ничто не мешает вам прямо по нажатию на кнопку в уведомлении запустить сразу сервис. В данном случае BroadcastReceiver явно лишний.

Comment: У меня почему то без него не работает... Хотя вы правы... Нужно проверить